# How to find if consensus on answer

Tags: python

I have the following three lists:

```
x = [
    (u'http://imdb.com/title/tt0926129/', None, None), 
    (u'http://imdb.com/title/tt0926129/', None, None)
    ]

y = [(1,), (2,), (1,)]

z = [(1,), (2,)]
```

How would I write a function to see if there is a majority of answers that are equivalent. In the above cases:

```
has_consensus(x) ==> True
has_consensus(y) ==> True
has_consensus(z) ==> False
```

I was thinking of doing a `.match()`, iterating through a forloop, but I think that might get a bit confusing. What is the best way to do the above?

Comment: How are you defining consensus? Majority vote?

Comment: Majority on 2 ==> 2, Majority on 3 ==> 2, Majority on 4 ==> 3, etc.

Comment: The collections.Counter is your friend :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Counter` class would make this pretty simple.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(x).most_common(1)[0]
(('http://imdb.com/title/tt0926129/', None, None), 2)
>>> Counter(y).most_common(1)[0]
((1,), 2)
>>> Counter(z).most_common(1)[0]
((2,), 1)
```

All you need to do is check if the most common element appears more than 50% of the time.

```
def has_consensus(l):
    return Counter(l).most_common(1)[0][1] * 2 > len(l)
```

Example:

```
>>> has_consensus(x)
True
>>> has_consensus(y)
True
>>> has_consensus(z)
False
```

Comment: dang - that's why I asked about majority :) But then has_consensus(z) would be False (and it died of cut'n'paste)

Comment: Oh man, that is an awesome answer. Thank you very much. I had it working with like 40 lines of code. And now it's 3!